# Checkstyle - How to ignore adding class file in output xml file

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin, sevntu-checkstyle

Is there any way to ignore showing the class file when it doesn't have the errors. I have checkstyle.xml with rules, and when I tried to build my project, the Checkstyle validates all of my files, and then it generates the output XML file. This XML tends to create HTML. I want to ignore to add the class file that validated through CheckStyle rule without any error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trim down files specified in the XML report Checkstyle generates. I would look into pre-processing the XML file first and removing these entries.